# How can you test a web app in a Windows 10 touch screen environment? (browserstack and sauselabs don't work)

Tags: windows, testing, web-applications, saucelabs, browserstack

I'm trying to test a website using Windows 10's touchscreen gestures.  We don't actually have a Windows 10 device with a touchscreen, but www.browserstack.com and www.saucelabs.com/‎ do not have this option.

What's the right way to test via Windows 10 touchscreen, short of actually buying a Windows 10 device with a touchscreen?

Answer (score 0):

While SauceLabs do provide [real devices](https://saucelabs.com/devices) they rely on [Appium](http://appium.io) to interact with the devices.

Microsoft have released a windows hardware lab kit ("[Windows HLK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/windows-hardware-lab-kit)").

There is more documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchscreen-tests).

This appears to the "right" way perform this testing.

Comment: @EricBaldwin, How did you go?

Comment: Andrew, This looks like a series of software tests to test the actual touchscreen hardware


So I don't think it will work for our use case

Comment: No worries, just trying to assist with your research.